# Installing fingerprinter driver on MSI stealth gs 77

Tags: drivers

I need help with installing a driver for my laptop. I have a goodix finger print reader, however the system is not recognising it. Is there a way for me to download directly from the manufacturer?

Official driver (windows 10/11):
https://us.msi.com/Laptop/Stealth-GS77-12UX/support?sku_id=88175#driver

Comment: Have you checked with goodix community?

https://developers.goodix.com/en/

Comment: Please add the output of `lsusb` terminal command

Comment: Bus 03 Service 004: ID 27c6:6094 Shenzhen Goodix Technology co., Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fingerprint reader is supported by `libfprint` 1.94.5 or later according to [this commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/commit/c74a1ab6d1b9e6c45706232012da0991499cea78).

The latest Ubuntu LTS has `libfprint` version 1.94.3 which does not cover your fingerprint reader.

The easiest way to get updated `libfprint` is to update to Ubuntu 23.04 or later.